# ubuntu multiple monitor issues

Tags: nvidia, multi-monitor, displaylink

This issue has only happened recently. Before, my setup was great. I was able to have 2 external monitors and have my laptop's lid closed. But now, when I have the monitors connected and working with my docking station, if I close the laptop (because I just want to use the 2 external monitors) everything freezes. I see the mouse on the monitor sometimes but that is it, everything else is black and not responsive.

I am running Ubuntu 20.04. I have uninstalled and reinstalled Displaylink (I am using a pluggable docking station). I deleted the monitor.xml files (this helped a little so that both monitors would connect properly). From what I have seen, my Nvidia card is "prime". I have tried installing the right drivers but that hasn't made a difference. (NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2070)

Here is what the logs look like, but I have not been able to make progress with it:

```
10:41:53 kernel: evdi: [E] evdi_painter_connect:856 Edid length too small
10:41:53 kernel: evdi: [E] evdi_painter_connect:856 Edid length too small
10:41:53 kernel: evdi: [E] evdi_painter_connect:856 Edid length too small
10:41:53 kernel: evdi: [E] evdi_painter_connect:856 Edid length too small
10:41:53 kernel: evdi: [E] evdi_painter_connect:856 Edid length too small
10:41:53 gdm-session-wor: gkr-pam: unable to locate daemon control file
10:41:45 kernel: overlayfs: missing 'lowerdir'
10:41:45 kernel: aufs aufs_fill_super:918:mount[1962]: no arg
10:41:43 kernel: evdi: [E] evdi_painter_connect:856 Edid length too small
10:41:43 kernel: evdi: [E] evdi_painter_connect:856 Edid length too small
10:41:43 kernel: evdi: [E] evdi_painter_connect:856 Edid length too small
10:41:43 kernel: evdi: [E] evdi_painter_connect:856 Edid length too small
10:41:43 kernel: evdi: [E] evdi_painter_connect:856 Edid length too small
10:41:43 wpa_supplicant: nl80211: Failed to create a P2P Device interface p2p-dev-wlp0s20f3
10:41:43 wpa_supplicant: nl80211: Failed to create a P2P Device interface p2p-dev-wlp0s20f3
10:41:43 wpa_supplicant: Failed to create interface p2p-dev-wlp0s20f3: -22 (Invalid argument)
10:41:43 wpa_supplicant: nl80211: kernel reports: Attribute failed policy validation
10:41:40 kernel: ucsi_ccg 0-0008: ucsi_ccg_init failed - -110
10:41:40 kernel: ucsi_ccg 0-0008: ucsi_ccg_init failed - -110
10:41:40 kernel: ucsi_ccg 0-0008: i2c_transfer failed -110
10:41:40 kernel: nvidia-gpu 0000:01:00.3: i2c timeout error e0000000
10:41:39 kernel: 
10:41:39 kernel: integrity: Problem loading X.509 certificate -65
10:41:39 kernel: integrity: Problem loading X.509 certificate -65
10:41:39 kernel: integrity: Problem loading X.509 certificate -65
10:41:39 kernel: x86/cpu: SGX disabled by BIOS
```

Comment: Have you configured the default action for closing the lid? That needs to be set to "do nothing". It should be available somewhere in your GUI settings.